# How to open multiple charts inside modal at a time on click in organization highcharts in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

In organization chart i am trying to open multiple charts same time on click on any node , but getting error while trying to open it.

Below is the code that i am referring. please help me on how can i open multiple highchart at same time (of different types i.e. line, bar highcharts).Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-n2zhsq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I couldn't recreate the error you were talking about, can you share the error you get when you click on the nodes?

Comment: i removed that error code and onclick event added.. how should i proceed further can you please help me?

Comment: i was referring this example https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/te0kd6f5/ .but now chart is not rendering

Comment: That jsfiddle renders fine for me

Comment: but when i am trying this in my above stackblitz code..it is not working. i want it like same way in this jsfiddle, but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that in the jsfiddle, there is code that creates a new Highcharts chart, but you don't seem to have that in your Angular component yet. You've got some more work to do it seems!

```
     events: {
        click: function() {
          const popup = document.getElementById('popup');
          const popupContent = document.getElementById('popupContent');

          popup.style.display = 'block';

          Highcharts.chart(popupContent, {
            chart: {
              width: 200
            },
            series: [{
              type: 'organization',
              data: nestedChartData[this.id]
            }]
          });

          this.series.chart.update({
            tooltip: {
              enabled: false
            }
          });
        }
      }
```

Comment: i have updated the stackblitz.. https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-n2zhsq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts.. now on departments chart are opening but i want different types of charts i.e. line, bar on click of nodes,  my problem is that how can i achieve it

Comment: I prepared a simplified demo with creating new HTML elements inside point events click.

Answer (score 0):

The chart type is related to the data, look I changed data Department1 to line type of data from API, [series.line.data](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data) and now you can open the charts in type of line.

```
const nestedChartData = {
  Department1: [1, 2, 4, 5],
  Department2: [
    [0, 1],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 8]
  ],
  Department3: [{
    x: 1,
    y: 9,
    name: "Point2",
    color: "#00FF00"
  }, {
    x: 1,
    y: 6,
    name: "Point1",
    color: "#FF00FF"
  }],
};
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-rqg4hy

EDIT

I prepared a simplified demo with creating new HTML elements inside point events click.

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fud5q19a/

Comment: thank you for your help, but i don't want to close the previous chart if i opened another one, what to do in such case?

Comment: to do: rebuild the function on the click so that it creates a component with a unique id each time, which will position itself block by block.

Comment: but it still closing previous one